# C#/.NET console applications that behave like normal Unix tools

Tags: c#, windows, unix, software-design

This question is regarding designing console applications in .NET that behave like normal Unix tools. The basic fundamental of Unix tools is that they can be chained together with 1 tool being able to take input from any compatible `stream` and giving output to any compatible `stream`.

If I'm writing console applications in .NET for Windows, what are the general things I need to follow for my tools to be of the same type?

Comment: One purpose, and do it good. Why not use cygwin?

Comment: What kind of program do you want to create? Or are you just asking what kind of principles do you want to follow *in general*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Do only one thing" is definitely one, but there are more:

1. Do only one thing and do it well
2. Output nothing on success (other than the result, of course)
3. Use stdin for the input, stdout for the output, and stderr for errors
4. Use non-zero exit codes to communicate failure

With this in mind, here's what is, in my opinion, a more "unixy" "to-uppercase" program in C#:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            var buf = new char[4096];
            while (true)
            {
                int read = Console.In.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                if (read == 0)
                    break;
                for (int i = 0; i < read; i++)
                    buf[i] = char.ToUpper(buf[i]);
                Console.Out.Write(buf, 0, read);
            }
            return 0;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine("ERROR: " + e.Message);
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Like a typical unixy program, you can run it without arguments and then it will be interactive, allowing you to type input manually on the console, terminated with Ctrl+Z, printing output whenever it receives a chunk of your input. Or you could pass it a file to process: `uppercase.exe <input.txt` and it will print the output to the console. Or you could redirect the output to a file too. Or you could pipe the input into it. Etc.

Answer (score 0):

The main principle behind *nix tools is [do one thing, and do it well](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?UnixDesignPhilosophy).

Let's say I set out to create a *nix style tool that converted the input to uppercase. It's a trivial example, but that allows me to post the whole program here.

Here's the source code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics.Contracts;

namespace Upperc {
  class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
      var input = Console.ReadLine();
      Contract.Assert(input != null);

      Console.WriteLine(input.ToUpperInvariant());
    }
  }
}
```

I took advantage of the fact that `Console` methods handle input and output and the standard streams. Example usage is:

```
> type example.txt | Upperc.exe > uppercased.txt
```

The input file is a plain text file:

```
example text file before processing
```

and the output file:

```
EXAMPLE TEXT FILE BEFORE PROCESSING
```